# Set the limit to allow author when make post!

Tags: posts, author, limit, members

I would like to ask something here,

The question is, is there any way to set the limit of post that an author can post? For example, I have a few authors on my site, but I want to allow each of them to make only 1 post and edit only post that they have posted.

Appreciate your answers. Thank you!

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50012/4771)

Comment: Hi! That's not what I want. What I am looking for is to limit the author to have only one post in life. Not to set the limit for a day. If possible, I want to do it without a plugin. Thanks!

Comment: the plugin linked in that answer does exactly that. if you don't want to use a plugin, then just look at how the code works and put it in your theme. but really in a plugin or in a theme there is absolutely no difference, hooks are hooks.