# How can I allow an User to publish only 5 posts per month?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-access, membership

I want to give my users the ability to publish posts. User Role 1: Can Publish 5 Posts per Month
User Role 2: Can publish 10 Posts per Month
And User Role 3: Can Publish 15 Posts per month

It should work with Gravity Forms post creating form
I have already tried the plugin: Bainternet Posts Creation Limits
But I can post with this user role hundreds of posts via gravity forms, no message is there and no limit...

And I want to echo on members area page if the user is logged in with User Role 2: You are a Gold Member and you already have published 2 of 5 Posts this month

How can I do that?
I'm completely new to wordpress development

and I havn't fount anything on Google....
Please help me!

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit user to publish post per day and per role?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49977/how-to-limit-user-to-publish-post-per-day-and-per-role)